# Infinite Loop in Test with React, Jest, Redux and Thunk

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, jestjs, redux-thunk

I have a React application with a Jest test suite. The application uses redux and the test suite uses redux-mock-store. I am using the react-thunk middleware to delay dispatching actions, since the application needs to sync data with a remote Firebase database. I would like my test suite to verify some condition after dispatching an action to Redux, like this:

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

// This is my custom async action generator.
import { asyncAction } from './some/path';

const createMockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);

test("Test", (done) => {
    const store = createMockStore({});
    const data = { ... };
    store.dispatch(asyncAction(data)).then(() => {
        expect(someCondition);
        done();
    });
});
```

The test uses the done handler returned by Jest to wait until the promise returned by store.dispatch completes. However, the promise is never executed, the test enters an infinite loop, and Jest fails with this exception:

```
Assertion failed: new_time >= loop->time, file c:\ws\deps\uv\src\win\core.c, line 309
error Command failed with exit code 3221226505.
```

At first I thought there was a problem with the promise returned by my custom async action generator, but notice how it is returning a promise from Firebase (look at the inner return statement, the outer return statement is the function dispatched by redux-thunk):

```
import database from '../firebase/firebase';

export const asyncAction = (data = {}) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return database.ref('someCollection').push(data).then((ref) => {
            dispatch({ type: 'SOME_TYPE', id: ref.key, ...data });
        });
    };
};
```

Then I thought maybe there's something wrong with how I set up Firebase, but I've verified that both the application and the test suite are saving data successfully. Here is the Firebase configuration:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';

firebase.initializeApp({ ... });

const database = firebase.database();
export { database as default };
```

Then I thought maybe there's something wrong with Redux or the redux-thunk middleware, but I've verified that the application is saving data successfully. Here is my Redux configuration:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, combineReducers, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

export default () => {
    const reducer = combineReducers({ ... });
    const enhancer = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk));
    return createStore(reducer, enhancer);
};
```

That all seems fine to me. I can't determine what is causing Jest to enter an infinite loop. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: where are you mocking the `database ` object?

Comment: Are you on node >= 14.6.0 ? (it contains a fix for libuv for Ice Lake cpu's)

Comment: @Ishank: That particular test is meant to be an integration test, so it's using the actual Fireabase databse on purpose.

Comment: @Caramiriel: Great suggestion! As it turns out, I am using an Ice Lake CPU and an older version of Node. Upgrading to the latest version (14.8.0 as of this writing) solved the problem. I don't think my test was that sophisticated, so there must be a larger issue with the handling of asynchronous logic in Jest that was causing Node to enter an infinite loop. If you'd like the bounty, please write an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've stumbled upon [this lengthy issue](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/1633) on Github (keywords '[Assertion failed: new_time >= loop->time](https://www.google.nl/search?q=Assertion%20failed%3A%20new_time%20%3E%3D%20loop-%3Etime)' on Google), dating almost three years ago. It's (libuv) a library Node uses for their asynchronous I/O, also the place where the problem resides. After a short read, the issue only seems to exist for Intel's Ice Lake CPU's (for now). While the issue is already fixed in the library, it requires a Node version of at least 14.6.0 which includes the fixed library implementation. Advised is updating to this version (probably the easiest option, but not the only option).

Answer (score 1):

> Assertion failed: new_time >= loop->time, file
> c:\ws\deps\uv\src\win\core.c, line 309 error Command failed with exit
> code 3221226505.

This seems to occur when the system clock is drifting. You can resolve it by trying any of the following:

1. Synchronize your Clock under Date & Time Settings on Windows 10.

or

2. selecting a different clock source, e.g. ACPI instead of TSC , or by tweaking settings in the BIOS.

or

3. doing a CMOS reset on your system.

or

4. check your onboard CMOS backup battery

or

5. **Install WSL** (Windows Subsystem for Linux).  This workaround works for many people

or

6. Or uninstall / reinstall Node and libuv / update to the latest version to benefit from any fixes for specific generations of processors.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. My system already has WSL. The issue was solved after upgrading to the latest version of Node, as suggested above. However, it is possible that your suggestions also solve the problem. Maybe whatever was fixed in Node from 14.6.0 was related to the system clock scenario you mention. Thanks again.

Comment: @ChristianCorrea Yeah if you google the error many people have solved it in different ways. I thought it was a good idea to collect all of them here.